# Is it possible to connect to microsoft outlook scheduling assistant from an android app?

Tags: android, web-services, outlook

I am trying to build an application which requires the information from microsoft outlook scheduling assistant.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is a huge question! Simple answer, no, there is no easy way to just plug it in, but that doesn't mean it isn't possible. Let's assume you're using the exchange server, you can create a request that returns you the availability info of a list of contacts over a period. This returns an array of integers detailing the status of that person during each hour/half hour of the period you sent.

You can then make a table layout with views depicting their availability with different colors. This is not an easy task. I recently had to do it for my company's email client and it took about 3 days of pretty hardwork to get a good looking UI with all the information you need.

For information on the protocols you send to get the availability info, check out the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463891(v=exchg.80).aspx). If you need any help doing this, please feel free to comment here. Unfortunately, I can't share the code I wrote, since I wrote it while working for IBM